# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts issue in Production Environment

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I was looking in posts similar to mine, but didn't find any response to my issue.

Recently the MySql server was changed, right now I'm using a different one,

I use this connection string in my asp.net vb web application project:

```
<add key="MySQLConnStr" value="server=xx.xxx.x.xx; user id=mysql_link;  database=mysql; pooling=false; password=xxxx"/>
```

Ok when I run the WebApp in my computer (development environment) it works perfect, now, in the host (production env.) I get the "Unable to connect..." error.

What could be the problem here??? I just changed the old MySql server ip for the new one.

I restarted the application pools in the host, restarted the webapp as well, but nothing.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your ASPNET user account has access to the new IP?

Comment: I'm sorry, where can I see that info?

Comment: I believe @CAbbott was referring to network-level issues (firewalls, etc.) Can you connect to the db using a MySQL client running on the web server using the creds from your config file?

Comment: I have two web apps there, and both stop working when the change of mysql server was made. Where can I check for the possible root cause?

Comment: @Basic - yes, that's what I was referring to accessibility. Usually when an address changes and something stops connecting it's some sort of access issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that your MySql runs on different port number?.
(any port different from the default 3306)
If so, add to your connection string "Port=xxxx;"

EDIT: It's also possible that your MySql Administrator has not given to the ip address/name of your server the permission to connect whilst has given them to your local pc

Comment: But, I'm able to access from my computer with the very same webapp and with the very same web.config, isn't that weird? Anyways I'll add the port to the string connection

Comment: Nope, it didn't work adding the port to the string connection :(

Comment: @Somebody - No, its not weird. It simply means that your Development machine has access to the MySQL Server and Production does not have it. Talk to the sys admin managing the server for possible issues.

Comment: Sys admin team solved the problem, it was the Steve's EDIT part, the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

complete connection string in c# code ..

```
 public MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=XXXX;database=yourDBname;Port=XXXX");
```

Thanks